# 'else' of if/else not executing when it should C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am designing a ATM system in C# and for the login function I am using an SQL server database to compare the card number and PIN entered to those on in the database. When the correct card number and PIN are entered everything works fine but when a incorrect value it entered nothing happens at all and I have been trying to figure it out for some time now. Does anyone have any ideas to what it might be? Even my university lecturer has no idea!

```
//Select all fields from the table 'ATMCards' using the connection previously created and use the SqlDataReader to read the values
```

To simplify it I have just put the messagebox.show in the else as all I want to do is at least have it trigger!

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ATMCards] WHERE (cardNumber = @cardNumber) AND (PIN = @PIN)", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cardNumber", cboxSimCard.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PIN", txtboxPIN.Text);

cmd.Connection = cn;
SqlDataReader r = null;
r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

//While the reader is in execution:
while (r.Read())
{
    //ADD IF NOT CONFISCATED DO THIS:
    if (((Boolean)(r["confiscated"]) == notConfiscated))
    {
        string cNum =  r["cardNumber"].ToString();
        string pin = r["PIN"].ToString();

        //Compare the results in the ATMCards table against those on the form used to log in
        if (string.Equals(cNum,cboxSimCard.Text) && string.Equals(pin,txtboxPIN.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Card number "+cNum+"  PIN "+pin); 
            //If the login details are correct then grant access to the menu screen by creating a new instance of it and hide the login form. Clear PIN to avoid the next user accessing the account
            MessageBox.Show("Open form all is good"); 
            txtboxPIN.Clear();
            Form myNewForm = new Menu();
            myNewForm.Show();
            this.Hide();
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Here"); 
        }
```

Comment: And you're sure `r["confiscated"] != notConfiscated` ?

Comment: You should (learn to) use a debugger here.

Comment: I hope this ATM machine is a learning assignment and not a commercial product. Plain text PIN for example?

Answer (score 8):

When an incorrect card number and pin pair are entered, no rows are returned from the database, so the `while(r.Read())` returns false immediately.

Comment: You answered while I was typing :-)

Comment: @Moo-Juice Ah I see, so where should I place the code for an incorrect card number and pin pair? Outside of the while(r.Read()) loop?

Comment: @TomCrook, yes you could have a check for `if(r.HasRows)` prior to the while loop, for example.

Comment: @TomCrook I think 2 rows is also an exception

Comment: @Moo-Juice I have implemented the if(r.HasRows) and and it works perfectly. If you were here I would give you a kiss for how long it has taken me to do. Thank you! :D

Comment: @TomCrook, no problem here to help :)  All you do now is click the little Tick mark on this answer and that marks this question as answered and so it's not left open.  And I get sweet, sweet karma :P

Answer (score 2):

When the there is no match for your `where` conditions the result set is returned with no rows. The first `r.Read` returns false and the contents of the `while` loop is never executed.

As [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) comments, if you debug the code this will be obvious.

Further to the simple answer ...

You shouldn't be executing your SQL like this. It leaves you open to injection attacks. You could use Linq-To-Entities or wrap you SQL in a call to `sp_ExecuteSQL`.

The PIN shouldn't be stored as plain text but rather as a secure hash of the PIN and other card details.

The card number shouldn't be stored in plain text. If you never have to read the card number is could be hashed. Otherwise encrypted

I assume you are validating the card details, using a modulo-13 or some industry standard check before passing the query to the database.

I'm not suggeting you could recreate what actually happens inside an ATM but, some nod to the security required with sensitive data would surely yield extra credit. (pun not intended)

Comment: Ah I see, so where should I place the code for an incorrect card number and pin pair? Outside of the while(r.Read()) loop?

Comment: Well, I think you only ever want one row right, less or more are both exceptions. I would handle the read first, so I could check for exceptions before processing the data.

Comment: @Tom Crook, could put the confiscated check in your where clause, unless you want to log use of a confiscated card.

Comment: No I do not want to log use of a confiscated card, just prevent a user using one.

Answer (score 0):

Man your code is

1. Not secure and maybe injected
2. Credit card and pin must be encrypted and u didnt
3. Your code will never show any message in failure case since if no data is reutrned the if clause inside while will not executed

you can use

```
if(reader.HasRows)
///then do happy case
else
//show error message
```

Comment: I think we shouldn't expect a basic university assignment to be implemented at world-class security level...

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that this :

```
if (string.Equals(cNum,cboxSimCard.Text) && string.Equals(pin,txtboxPIN.Text))
```

Does somethign wrong. Try to use an overload of the same function with [String.Equals(String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx). Like this

```
if (cNum.Equals(cboxSimCard.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&   pin.Equals(txtboxPIN.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```